# Buildozer - Log doesn't show specific error

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I'm trying to build .apk with kivy/buildozer in VM Mint Linux. Actually i just created .apk successfully about 1 week ago. But now i created new folder and tried minimal kivy example for build but it returns me that log below. After that, i tried to build same apk which created 1 week ago, it returns me same output. I have only 1 android near so maybe my android has problems but i need to know how to catch error code in log. Any tips would be awasome.

main.py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {"d":.2,"t":"in_out_expo"}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == 'win':
    Window.size = (450, 720)

class S1(Screen):
    pass

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class orbitest(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    orbitest().run()
```

.kv:

```
<SM>:
    S1:
        name: 's1'
<S1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        AnchorLayout:
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'TEST BUTON1'
                size_hint_x:.7
        AnchorLayout:
            MDFlatButton:
                text: 'TEST BUTON2'
                size_hint_x:.7
```

buildozer:

```
... 
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,pillow
... (nothing changed)
```

Log:

```
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@d4cfdf3, Ic907de5ed0, 1601055299) (Date:09/25/20)'>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
22276 22310 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
22276 22310 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
22276 22310 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 22310 (SDLThread), pid 22276 (SDLActivity)
3604  3604 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/vendor/bin/cnss_diag identical 2 lines
724   724 E qdmetadata: paramType 2048 not supported
3604  3604 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/vendor/bin/cnss_diag identical 1 line
3604  3604 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/vendor/bin/cnss_diag identical 3 lines
22316 22316 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
595   595 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 22310
22316 22316 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 22276 (target tid = 22310)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/laurel_sprout/laurel_sprout:11/RKQ1.200903.002/V12.0.26.0.RFQMIXM:user/release-keys'
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-22316 22316 F DEBUG   : pid: 22276, tid: 22310, name: SDLThread  >>> org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk <<<
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : uid: 10449
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000001  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000003  x3  000000000008a084
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x4  b40000727e9a21cc  x5  0000000000000003  x6  b40000727e9a247c  x7  b40000722e90c850
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x8  0000000000000003  x9  0000000000000003  x10 00000070ff4c5374  x11 b40000727e9a21d4
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x12 b40000736e99d54c  x13 00000070ff4c537c  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000000000000000
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000000000000001  x17 0000000000000000  x18 0000000000000000  x19 00000070ff4c54d0
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x20 b40000727e9a2110  x21 b40000736e99b0a0  x22 0000000000000000  x23 0000000000000003
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x24 b40000722e90c8e0  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000001
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000068  x29 00000070ff4c5380
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007151f44f1c  sp  00000070ff4c5340  pc  0000007151f57768  pst 0000000060000000
22316 22316 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: Function names and BuildId information is missing for some frames due
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: to unreadable libraries. For unwinds of apps, only shared libraries
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: found under the lib/ directory are readable.
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000394768  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (!!!0000!7b4d3d680da059de73d7f9795dc456!d4cfdf3!+368) (BuildId: 58fb42c513e51f274b9cfcc69e80584f)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0000000000381f18  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (!!!0000!f56be09eb88f86833124f1df42e945!d4cfdf3!+4176) (BuildId: 58fb42c513e51f274b9cfcc69e80584f)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000176f88  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (!!!0000!6b200851123c7898055fe62ff9f71f!d4cfdf3!+616) (BuildId: 58fb42c513e51f274b9cfcc69e80584f)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000016ec10  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (!!!0000!77df12deb6a622478efa8fb9929034!d4cfdf3!+376) (BuildId: 58fb42c513e51f274b9cfcc69e80584f)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000000ac58  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/vbo.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000000143a4  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000001606c  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 0000000000008268  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/compiler.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 0000000000012290  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #40 pc 0000000000011ad0  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #41 pc 0000000000014b44  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #42 pc 000000000001606c  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #43 pc 0000000000020958  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/instructions.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #44 pc 00000000001727cc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #45 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #46 pc 0000000000234cfc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9272)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #47 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #48 pc 000000000016b978  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #49 pc 0000000000025c24  /data/data/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/_event.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #50 pc 0000000000172410  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #51 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #52 pc 0000000000234cfc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9272)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #53 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #54 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #55 pc 0000000000234cfc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9272)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #56 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #57 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #58 pc 0000000000234cfc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9272)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #59 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #60 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #61 pc 00000000002347e0  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7964)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #62 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #63 pc 0000000000238eec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #64 pc 0000000000234cfc  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9272)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #65 pc 00000000002327a4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #66 pc 00000000002326ec  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (PyEval_EvalCode+104)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #67 pc 0000000000278de4  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (_PyRun_SimpleFileObject+1188)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #68 pc 000000000027968c  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.10.so (PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+60)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #69 pc 0000000000002740  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libmain.so (SDL_main+2664) (BuildId: d905a96c73601738a911420f2af27f7a882850aa)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #70 pc 00000000000b0430  /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/lib/arm64/libSDL2.so (Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeRunMain+772) (BuildId: 94785fafc39e00928bd7c714ad37f45bfcb53efa)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #71 pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #72 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #73 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #74 pc 000000000031831c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #75 pc 000000000030e648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #76 pc 000000000067f49c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #77 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #78 pc 000000000000c346  [anon:dalvik-classes3.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~eo7OEfADNuadMGSSfSur5A==/org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk-6rKY8fcX3EC5uwtA4RoZjw==/base.apk!classes3.dex] (org.libsdl.app.SDLMain.run+166)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #79 pc 000000000067e21c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1808) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #80 pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #81 pc 00000000000eb840  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #82 pc 0000000000305c44  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.11487796752256266877)+268) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #83 pc 000000000066b24c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #84 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #85 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #86 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #87 pc 0000000000554cbc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #88 pc 00000000005a4058  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1308) (BuildId: c58eb791dd4db5a5fc1ef4a3404cd082)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #89 pc 00000000000b0048  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 8d77279a411c99f8bc6edb79c76340fb)
22316 22316 F DEBUG   :       #90 pc 00000000000503c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 8d77279a411c99f8bc6edb79c76340fb)
1446 22322 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
1446  9357 I ActivityManager: Process org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk (pid 22276) has died: prcp TOP
1446  6681 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{451c137 u0 org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
741   741 I sensors-hal: activate:210, android.sensor.accelerometer/11 en=0
1446  6681 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '451c137 org.asmetestorbital.test.orbitalapk/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)'
```

Comment: I figured out that if i use only kivy functions (without kivymd) error gone. Also if i install kivymd==1.1.1 as [kivymd says](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD), error occurs even open application on linux somehow. `pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip` solved this problem. Im still trying to catch kivymd error on apk side.

Answer (score 0):

After trying pure kivy test app which haven't kivymd widgets, figured out that problem was about kivymd. So as kivymd github page says, adding `kivymd==1.1.1` to requirements results was same.

But after using kivymd(master) problem solved but few widget disabled (like Snackbar). I think it was all about kivymd pull request adress changes or smthng not sure. I hope it helps if you have same log outputs like me. Please let us know if you figure these why same code doesn't work after several days and how to catch error from upper log out. Thanks.